# Present a ViewController, dismiss it, and then segue into another View

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to do the following:

1. User presses button
2. `UIImagePickerController` pops up
3. User selects image
4. `UIImagePickerController` is dismissed
5. Segue into another ViewController

As of now, I have it set up that when the user presses a button, a UIImagePickerController is initialized and presented with presentViewController. It is also delegated to the class that this button is linked to as well. After the user picks an image, imagePickerController is called, and `dismissViewControllerAnimated` is also called. Then, `performSegueWithIdentifier` is called. However, this last step throws the following warning, and then does not segue:

> 2016-09-15 03:45:44.870 Food Diary[9941:1540144] Warning: Attempt to present 
>        on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

I am very new to Swift and iOS development, what does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Show some code at that place, probably you will need to put the `self.present` on the `self.dismiss`'s completion block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perform segue on completion of dismiss of `UIImagePickerController`

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    // your code
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueIdentifier", sender: self)
    })
}
```

**Note:** With sender I have passed current Controller object you can any object that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to using these two lines code during presenting and dissmising your view controller

Presenting :

```
self.view.window.rootviewcontroller.presentViewController("yourVC",animated:true, nil)
```

Dissmising :

```
self.view.window.rootViewController.dismissViewController(animated:true completion:nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

It stays on the same ViewController because the `UIImagePickerController` is still in view hierarchy a the d second ViewController cannot be added on top of `UIImagePickerController`. To fix, you need to wrap your segue in the completion of `UIImagePickerCopntroller` dismissal like this:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "StartToMain", sender: nil)
})
```